# Crash on Join with Fluent in Vapor

Tags: swift, postgresql, join, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have two models and they have one-many relation. Here are my classes.

**Booking**

```swift
final class Booking: PostgreSQLModel {
    /// The unique identifier for this `Todo`.
    var id: Int?

    /// A title describing what this `Todo` entails.
    var user_id: User.ID
    var product_id: Product.ID
    var count: Int

    /// Creates a new `Todo`.
    init(id: Int? = nil, user_id: User.ID, product_id: Product.ID, count: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.count = count
    }
}
extension Booking {
    var user: Parent<Booking, User> {
        return parent(\.user_id)
    }
    var product: Parent<Booking, Product> {
        return parent(\.product_id)
    }
}
```

**Product**

```swift
final class Product: PostgreSQLModel {
    /// The unique identifier for this `Todo`.
    var id: Int?

    /// A title describing what this `Todo` entails.
    var name: String
    var image_url: String
    var description: String
    var price: Int?

    /// Creates a new `Todo`.
    init(id: Int? = nil, name: String, image_url: String, description: String, price: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.image_url = image_url
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
    }
}
extension Product {
    var bookings: Children<Product, Booking> {
        return children(\.product_id)
    }
}
```

Now i want to fetch all bookings of a user and with each booking i want to fetch the product information as well. So for this i have tried to join `Booking` and `Product` table but this throws an exception.

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: ⚠️ CoreError: `Parent<Booking, Product>` does not conform to `ReflectionDecodable`.
>   - id: CoreError.ReflectionDecodable
>   : file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang_Fall2018/swiftlang_Fall2018-1000.11.42/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 184
>   Program ended with exit code: 9

Here is my code for join.

```swift
let booking = Booking.query(on: req).join(\Product.bookings, to:\Booking.product).filter(\.user_id == userID).decode(BookingM.self).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, with the query that you have, you don't need to join the the `Product` table, because you never query on it or decode it.

Your `join` statement:

```
.join(\Product.bookings, to:\Booking.product)
```

Is incorrect. Instead of joining the `Product.bookings` property, you should join to the `Product.id` property, because the product's ID is what the `Booking.product` property contains.

So your Fluent query should look something like this:

```
let booking = Booking.query(on: req).join(\Booking.product, to:\Product.id).filter(\.user_id == userID).all()
```

I removed the `.decoding` call because the query already decodes the the query result too `Booking`.

To use your `bookings` property, your query would look like this:

```
let booking = product.bookings.query(on: req).filter(\Booking.user_id == userID).all()
```